# Deleting full matched elements from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to know if there is a possible way to erase a whole matched list from a big list in Python. For example,

```
a = ["2", "1", "2", "x"]
```

I want to know if there is a way to erase the `"2", "x"` from the list. Note, the position of the elements of the list is random but in any random position the `"2"` and `"x"` will be side by side i.e. after the `"2"` there will be `"x"`.

Comment: Yes for sure there are ways to do this. Have you tried anything yet? finding all the index values of 2? then checking theos index + 1 to see if the next element is an x? then you will know the index positions of all the 2 follows by x items

Comment: Also can 2 and x appear after each other more than once in the list ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, finding all indices of 2 if following element is x is the right approach. Using that approach:

```
# Your input list
list_a = ["2", "1", "2", "x", "2", "x", "2", "x"]

# Storing index of 2 and its next element if that next element is x 
indices_to_store = []
for i, v in enumerate(list_a):
    if list_a[i]=="2" and list_a[i+1]=="x":
       indices_to_store.append(i)
       indices_to_store.append(i+1)

# output list using list comprehension
new_list = [list_a[i] for i,v in enumerate(list_a) if i not in indices_to_store]
# ['2', '1']
```